# Calculating limit of the form of 1×inf - inf

Tags: calculus, analysis

f(x) is defined on every real number x, 0 <= f(x) <=1 for all x, it is differentiable,$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf'(x)dx$ converges, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = 0$
Then, what is $\lim_{x\to \infty} { {xf(x)-x}} $? 
My intuition says that it is 0 but I don't know how to prove it. Can you give me any hint?

Comment: In the title, you mean 1 rather than 0, right?

Comment: Hans/ oh, you are right